# Prevent quartz from running jobs as soon as it loads

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I Have a quartz job, scheduled to run at specific time, however as soon as job is loaded it runs once irrespective of time and then runs again at scheduled time.

How to limit it to run only at scheduled time and not as soon as it is loaded?

```
public void Initialze()
    {
        _schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        _scheduler = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        _scheduler.Start();            
    }

 public StatusObject AddJobToQuartzScheduler(T_BIT_Scheduler item)
    {
        return AddJobToQuartzScheduler(new QuartzModel { BeginDateTime = item.BeginDateTime, IdeaId = item.IdeaId, IsActive = item.IsActive, SchedulerExpression = item.SchedulerExpression, SchedulerID = item.SchedulerID, SchedulerName = item.SchedulerName, SchedulerType = item.SchedulerType });
    }


    public StatusObject AddJobToQuartzScheduler(QuartzModel quartzData, bool AddToDB = false)
    {
        IGlobalFunction globalFunction = new GlobalFunction();
        try
        {
            int schedulerId = quartzData.SchedulerID;
            if (AddToDB)
            {
                using (var dbContext = new DBEntities())
                {
                    IQuartzRepository quartzRepository = new QuartzRepository(dbContext);
                    schedulerId = quartzRepository.Add(new T_BIT_Scheduler { BeginDateTime = quartzData.BeginDateTime, IdeaId = quartzData.IdeaId, IsActive = quartzData.IsActive, SchedulerExpression = quartzData.SchedulerExpression, SchedulerName = quartzData.SchedulerName, SchedulerType = quartzData.SchedulerType }).SchedulerID;
                }

            }


            CronExpression cron = new CronExpression(quartzData.SchedulerExpression);
            if (cron.GetNextValidTimeAfter(DateTime.Now) == null)
            {
                globalFunction.FailureObject("Invalid Time");
            }

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity(quartzData.SchedulerName + "Trigger", "BrightIdeaGroup")
                .StartAt(quartzData.BeginDateTime)
                .WithCronSchedule(cron.CronExpressionString)
                .Build();

            //task.TaskName+"Job" is added to give unique job name
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<QuartzJob>()
                       .WithIdentity(schedulerId + "Job", "ScheduledJobGroup")
                       .UsingJobData("IdeaID", quartzData.IdeaId)
                        .UsingJobData("Type", quartzData.SchedulerType)
                       .Build();

            // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
            _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            return globalFunction.SuccessObject("Successfully Added the job");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return globalFunction.FailureObject(e.Message);
        }
        // log if a job failed to get add


    }
```

Comment: It's hard to debug that code just by looking at it. Set a break point in the job that's being called and take a look at the callstack to see if it's actually quartz that's running the job. You could also remove everything but the scheduler, trigger and job creation to see if the problem still occurs then.

Comment: Could it be that "quartzData.BeginDateTime" used in ".StartAt(quartzData.BeginDateTime)" is set in the past / to the current time?

Comment: .StartAt(quartzData.BeginDateTime) is set in the past. but I want is, even if begin date is past date, let it run only when next time occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use **objSchedular.StartDelayed(new TimeSpan(Trigger Interval));**
It Will Trigger First Job Execution at at scheduled time and not as soon as it is loaded...Revert if it is working.

Comment: Can you let me know what exactly to pass in (Trigger Interval)?